# Ckeditor initial disabled widget button state

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I'm currently developing a Ckeditor 4 widget, but I run into the following issue. I'd like my widget button initially disabled untill an AJAX call is done and has a particular result.

The widget code:

```
editor.widgets.add('smartobject', {
            dialog: 'smartobject',
            pathName: lang.pathName,
            upcast: function(element) {
                return element.hasClass('smartObject');
            },

            init: function() {
                this.setData('editorHtml', this.element.getOuterHtml());
            },
            data: function() {
                var editorHtml = this.data.editorHtml;
                var newElement = new CKEDITOR.dom.element.createFromHtml(editorHtml);
                newElement.replace(this.element);
                this.element = newElement;
            }
        });
```

The button is added as follows:

```
        editor.ui.addButton && editor.ui.addButton('CreateSmartobject', {
            label: lang.toolbar,
            command: 'smartobject',
            toolbar: 'insert,5',
            icon: 'smartobject'
        });
```

With this code it seems I can't configure the default disabled state.
So I searched in the docs, and thought I had the fix.
The following code addition **seemed** to work:

```
editor.$smartobjectPluginPreloadAvailableSmartobjectsPromise.done(function(availableSmartobjects) {
            if (availableSmartobjects && availableSmartobjects.length > 0) {
                editor.getCommand('smartobject').enable();
            }
        });

        editor.addCommand('smartobject', new CKEDITOR.dialogCommand('smartobject', {
            startDisabled: 1
        }));
```

After adding this code the button is initially disabled, and enabled after the AJAX call is completed. So far so good. After a while I tried to add a new 'smartobject', but after completing the dialog config, the widgets 'data' function is not called. When **editing** an already existing smartobject by doubleclicking the element in the editor, still works..

I've probably mixed up different 'code styles' for adding a button, but I can't find the fix I need for my use case..

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seemed my idea was not possible through the ckeditor widget API and I combined some API logic which was not meant to be combined..

For now I simply fixed it by initially hiding the widgets button through CSS and adding a class to the button after the AJAX call succeeded:

```
.cke_button__createsmartobject {
  display: none !important;
}

.cke_button__createsmartobject.showButton {
  display: block !important;
}
```

And the JS logic:

```
editor.ui.addButton && editor.ui.addButton('CreateSmartobject', {
  label: lang.toolbar,
  command: 'smartobject',
  toolbar: 'insert,5',
  icon: 'smartobject'
});

// Enable the button if smartobjects are allowed for the itemtype of this editor.
editor.$smartobjectPluginPreloadAvailableSmartobjectsPromise.done(function(availableSmartobjects) {
    if (availableSmartobjects && availableSmartobjects.length > 0) {
        jQuery('.cke_button__createsmartobject').addClass('showButton');
    }
});
```

It's not the solution I'm most proud of, but it works for now.

Comment: Well, your solution might not be satisfying  but it is quick, simple, clear, and effective. At root it's also such an obvious one (display:none;) that I almost feel embarrassed to admit I hadn't thought of it in trying to do something not too different with a plugin icon, and that you saved me a lot of time. +1